# Convert htaccess rule to config.web on windows server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, server, web-config, plesk

I need to use this rule on a Plesk Windows server.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(invoice|offer)\/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dev.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Can someone show me how to use this rule in the `web.conf` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting web.config should look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^\/(invoice|offer)\/(.*)"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://dev.domain.com/{R:1}"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```